# update numeric variables when changed in prototype function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add two numbers but for some reason I am not getting NaN.

Following is the sample code

```
function Slider(container, nav, pagination){
    this.articleWidth = this.div.width() + 20;
    this.divWidth = 960;
    this.articleMargin = 0;
    this.pageMargin = this.divWidth + this.articleMargin
}

Slider.prototype.articleTransition = function(pageNum){
    var currArticle = pageNum -1;
    this.articleMargin = currArticle * this.articleWidth;
    this.container.animate({'margin-left': -this.articleMargin});
}
```

Here everything works as expected. But `this.pageMargin` is always 0 even though `this.articleMargin`'s value is changing in the `articleTransition` function. And when I console log `this.pageMargin` is says `NaN`. I am trying to change value of `this.articleMargin`'s value, everytime it is being invoked in the function.

Here is how I am invoking the function in my HTML.

```
    var slider = new Slider($('div#contentSleeve'), $('a.anav'), $('ul#scroller li'));

    slider.pagination.live('click', function(){
        slider.articleTransition($(this).data('num'));
    });
```

Comment: where do you defined articleWidth?

Comment: sorry I missed it in the question. I have edited the question again.

Comment: and this.div.width() is set as well or do you get the .div from somewhere else?

Comment: Did you mean to store the `container` argument as `this.div`?

Comment: I'm starting to suspect that you're using `this` instead of `container`?

Comment: I am invoking this function from the footer of my HTML. I am passing the div as an argument. I will add that code as well.

Comment: @AtesGoral No. when the value of this.articleMargin is updated in the articleTransition, I want it updated outside the function as well. So I can use the updated value in another function which I will be writing later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did fix this. All I had to do was to create a global variable that will store the value of both pageMargin and ArticleMargin.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's because you are calling in anonymous function scope. Try like this:

```
slider.articleTransition.call(slider, $(this).data('num'));
```